# One PHP statement to use result of IF statement for assignment

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

I have a situation where I have a function that does some database retrieval and either returns a value or an error.  I'd like to have a single statement that calls the function and depending on result either assigns the returned value or a default value.

Using the tenary operator I could do something like this:

```
$val=(getVal($param)!='error' ? getVal($param) : "default");
```

but I don't want to have to call getVal twice because it excutes database queries and is expensive on performance.

I could also do it in two statements, but if possible I just want one.  Appreciate any help.

Comment: keep it in two statements for better performance

Comment: Even if there are ways, none of them offer better readability than two statements. So you'd better keep it as a two liner.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`$val=(($result=getVal($param))!='error' ? $result : "default");`

Comment: No, it works great.  I guess the parentheses around the assignment statement evaluates the $result variable so it is available for the rest of the tenary statement. Thanks for all the input.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways I am aware of (maybe there is more).

Either you first assign function result to a variable and then use if:

```
$res = getVal($param);
$val = ($res != 'error' ? $res : "default");
```

*Note: This is possibly the best option both for readability and performance.*

---

Or you modify function from this:

```
function getVal($param) {
   ...
   return $something;
}
```

to this:

```
function getVal ($param, &$result) {
   ...
   $result = $something;
   return $something;
}
```

And use it:

```
$val = (getVal($param,$res) != 'error' ? $res : "default");
```

But this looks fishy to me